# Python regex match last word of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
"crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 540 match address 3P-DC-CRYPTO"
```

And, I am trying to match with a regex only `3P-DC-CRYPTO`

So far, I have managed to write the below regex :

```
crypto_acl = re.findall("address [-\w+]*",output)
```

However, it matches `address 3P-DC-CRYPTO`

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to match the last word, you don't have to use regex: `output.split()[-1]` will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=address\s)[-\w+]*` for your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/62YVWF/1).

Comment: Since I have more than 1 line to be checked, your option is the right one for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No regex needed, actually:

```
string = "crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 540 match address 3P-DC-CRYPTO"

# check for address as well
words = string.split()
if words[-2] == 'address':
    last_word = words[-1]
    print(last_word)
```

This checks for `address` and then captures the last word.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by capturing the desired word like this:

```
>>> crypto_acl = re.findall("address ([-\w+]*)",output)
>>> crypto_acl
['3P-DC-CRYPTO']
```

Also, since you've mentioned in the question that you need the last word of a string, you can simply do it like this, without explicitly looking for the word after `address`:

```
>>> crypto_acl = re.findall(r"\b([-\w+]+)$",output)
>>> crypto_acl
['3P-DC-CRYPTO']
#or simply 
>>> crypto_acl = output.split()[-1]
>>> crypto_acl
'3P-DC-CRYPTO'
```

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/YASzrZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try with regex search,

```
import re

str = "crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 540 match address 3P-DC-CRYPTO"

result = re.search(r'(address .*)', str)

result.group()                          # return as 'address 3P-DC-CRYPTO'


result = re.search(r'address (.*)', str)

result.group()                     #  return as 'address 3P-DC-CRYPTO'
result.group(0)                   #  return as 'address 3P-DC-CRYPTO'
result.group(1)                  #  return as '3P-DC-CRYPTO'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Positive Lookbehind and capture the group():

```
import re
pattern=r"(?<=address )[\w-]+"
string_1="crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 540 match address 3P-DC-CRYPTO"
match=re.finditer(pattern,string_1,re.M)
for i in match:
    print(i.group())
```